# Pappus's Centroid Theorem

Tags: centroid, solid-of-revolution

Pappus's Centroid Theorem may refer to one of two theorems.

**Theorem 1:**

The surface area of a solid of revolution is the arc length of the generating curve multiplied by the distance traveled by the centroid of the curve.

**Theorem 2:**

The volume of a solid of revolution is the area between the generating curve and the rotation axis multiplied by the distance traveled by the centroid of the curve.

I've managed to prove 2nd theorem like this:

Let the $x$-axis be the rotation axis and $y=f(x)$, $a \leq x \leq b$  be the generating curve. The $y$-coordinate of the centroid, $\bar y$, is then 
$$\frac{1}{2A}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)^2dx$$

where
$$A=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$$

So, we have that

$$2\pi\bar yA=2\pi A\left(\frac{1}{2A}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)^2dx\right)=\pi\int_a^bf(x)^2dx$$

My question is, how can we prove the second theorem?

Comment: Just asking: Do you know how to parametrize a surface (of rotation) and calculate the area element?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang No, I don't think so. I could try to learn how by looking it up though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}$If $\bigl(x(t), z(t)\bigr)$, $a \leq t \leq b$, parametrizes a smooth plane curve $C$ in the half-plane $x > 0$, the surface $S$ swept out by revolving $C$ about the $z$-axis may be parametrized by
$$
X(s, t) = \bigl(x(t) \cos s, x(t) \sin s, z(t)\bigr),\qquad
a \leq t \leq b,\quad 0 \leq s \leq 2\pi.
$$
The partial derivatives are
\begin{align*}
\frac{\dd X}{\dd s} &= \bigl(-x(t) \sin s, x(t) \cos s, 0\bigr), \\
\frac{\dd X}{\dd t} &= \bigl(x'(t) \cos s, x'(t) \sin s, z'(t)\bigr);
\end{align*}
Their cross product is
$$
\frac{\dd X}{\dd s} \times \frac{\dd X}{\dd t}
  = -x(t) \bigl(z'(t) \cos s, z'(t) \sin s, x'(t)\bigr);
$$
the area element is
$$
\left\lVert\frac{\dd X}{\dd s} \times \frac{\dd X}{\dd t}\right\rVert ds\, dt
  = x(t) \sqrt{z'(t)^{2} + x'(t)^{2}}\, ds\, dt.
\tag{1}
$$
The surface area of $S$ is
$$
\int_{a}^{b} \int_{0}^{2\pi} x(t) \sqrt{z'(t)^{2} + x'(t)^{2}}\, ds\, dt
  = 2\pi \int_{a}^{b} x(t)\sqrt{z'(t)^{2} + x'(t)^{2}}\, dt.
$$
If
$$
\ell = \int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{z'(t)^{2} + x'(t)^{2}}\, dt
$$
denotes the arc length of $C$, the area of $S$ becomes
$$
2\pi \int_{a}^{b} x(t) \sqrt{z'(t)^{2} + x'(t)^{2}}\, dt
  = 2\pi\, \ell \left(\frac{1}{\ell} \int_{a}^{b} x(t) \sqrt{z'(t)^{2} + x'(t)^{2}}\, dt\right)
  = \ell\, (2\pi\, \bar{x}),
$$
the length of $C$ times the circumference of the circle swept by the centroid of $C$.

Comment: Actually, is it possible to derive that the surface area of S is $$2\pi \int_a^b x(t)\sqrt{z'(t)^2+x'(t)^2}dt$$ from the fact that the lateral surface area of a frustum is $$\pi\left(R+r\right)l$$?

Comment: Yes, that looks fine: If $x = \frac{R + r}{2}$ is the distance from the central circle of the frustum to the axis of rotation and $l = d\ell$ is an element of arc length, then an infinitesimal frustum has lateral area $2\pi\, x\, d\ell$.